# Angular 4 - 2 way data binding on input element

Tags: angular, data-binding

I'm currently using Angular 4 with ionic to build an input form. I have a scenario where I want to have an input field automatically change an entered value to 2 decimal places on change e.g. a user input of 5.132 becomes 5.13.

Thus far I have the following input defined:

```
<ion-input type="number" [ngModel]="printData.sale" (ngModelChange)="updateSaleValue($event)" step="0.01"
                 name="sale" required lessThan="original" extraLessThan="extraSale" reverse2="true" min="0.01" #sale="ngModel"></ion-input>
```

The updateSaleValue function runs a simple rounding function to two decimal places and assigns the result to printData.sale.

When I test this the first time the change is triggered the function runs as expected (value is rounded to 2 dp and the input value in the page displays the output).

However, any subsequent change triggers the updateSaleValue function (which I can see as I added a console log) but the corresponding value displayed in the input element is not updated ie. 5.132 remains 5.132.

Is anyone able to explain why this is so and suggest how I might get this to work?

---

As requested the controller function is as follows

```
public updateSaleValue(string: price) {
  console.log('I'm here');
  this.printData.sale = formatFunction();
}
```

Comment: Could you add the code for the UpdateSaleValue function? You are saying that the in the second and subsequent runs printData.sale has the correct value but it is not reflected in the DOM?

Comment: @Fjut added it - its simple though!

Comment: I would also be interested in the format function:).  Why are you not passing the price to it? Is also does not look correct that you first define the type and then the name of the param. Is that pseudo code?

Comment: Hi yes its sudo code as I can't remember the exact implementation. I ended up using blur instead but wanted to know the answer so posted a question here

Comment: @robbannn if I use this syntax how can I bind a callback to the change event so I'm able to execute the 2 decimal place rounding functionality?